# Can't create an appropriate expression to click on it using selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Can't figure out how to create any expression to click on it. Because if i create a css selector using `href` then it will throw an error. However, I don't see any choice for me to click on the below link using selenium. It's perhaps my limitation. Any help as to how i can click on the link within the below elements will be highly appreciated.

This are the elements:

```
<td nowrap="nowrap">
    <a href="Property.aspx?prop_id=250369" onmouseover="window.status='View Details';return true;" onmouseout="window.status='';return true;">
        <img src="images/viewdetails.gif">
    View Details</a>
</td>
```

I need to click on view details. Thanks.

Comment: Did you read my comment? It's pretty short. See especially `shares that research, code attempts, and results`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is too little page context to give detailed answer. Limiting tou your example just `a` is enough. But obviously this is just a *part* of a bigger page.

Css selector is not limited to one level of hierarchy. Utilize the surroundings.
Even with your example it can be `td a` or `td > a`. Look at upper levels, maybe one of them has id or specific class?

Comment: Thanks Mike Makarov, it's good idea to go with. get back to you soon. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks man. It worked. I tried with `(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[nowrap='nowrap'] a")`

Comment: One more thing for the clarity. There are not much elements there in that page, so I pasted the gist part here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("View Details")).click();
```

Comment: Although you are late, this is the solution I was after. Thanks. +1 for this.